# I have 4 different dates here in my div I need to apply active color to most recent future date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, colors

We have 4 different dates here

```
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2018-03-30"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2018-04-29"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-05-25"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-07-26"></div>
```

The most recent date should be of active class and future and old dates should be inactive class

For example

```
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2018-03-30"></div>
```

the above `<div>` should be in `green` color and the other 3 `divs` should be of `red` color

```
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2018-04-29"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-05-25"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-07-26"></div>
```

I need javascript or jquery snippet to do this?

Javascript snippet

```
$(function() {
    var currentDate = Date.now();
    var a = new Date(currentDate);
    $(".grid-item").each(function() {
        var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
        var date = Date.parse(specifiedDate);
        var b = new Date(date);
        if (!isNaN(b) && b.getMonth() == a.getMonth() && b.getDay()== 
           a.getDay() && b.getYear() == a.getYear()) {
          $(this).addClass('today');
        }
        else if(!isNaN(b) && a - b > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('past');
        }
        else {
        $(this).addClass('future');
    }
});
```

});

css

```
.grid-item {
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  background:red;
  margin:10px;
}

.past {
     background:black;
}

.future {
     background:blue;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Care to share some JS code?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: this is my jquery and css snippet

Comment: $(function() {
    var currentDate = Date.now();
    var a = new Date(currentDate);
    $(".grid-item").each(function() {
        var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
        var date = Date.parse(specifiedDate);
        var b = new Date(date);
        if (!isNaN(b) && b.getMonth() == a.getMonth() && b.getDay()== a.getDay() && b.getYear() == a.getYear()) {
            $(this).addClass('today');
        }
        else if(!isNaN(b) && a - b > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('past');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('future');
        }
    });
});

Comment: .grid-item {
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
  background:red;
  margin:10px;
}

.past {
     background:black;
}

.future {
     background:blue;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the dates and store it on an array.

Then add class `.red` to all `.grid-item`. Filter the `div` that has the same date with `date` element 0. And remove the class `red` add the class `green`

```js
//Get the dates and sort it
var date = $(".grid-item").map(function(){ return $(this).data('date') }).get().sort(function(a,b){
    var f = function(d){[y,m,d] = d.split("-");return [y,m,d];}
    var t = new Date();
    return Math.abs( t.getTime() - new Date(...f(a)).getTime() ) - Math.abs( t.getTime() - new Date(...f(b)).getTime() );
});

//Assign Class
$(".grid-item").addClass('red').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('date') === date[0];
}).removeClass('red').addClass('green');
```

```css
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2018-03-30"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2018-04-29"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-05-25"></div>
<div class="grid-item" data-date="2015-07-26"></div>
```

---

If you want to base the order from the content and the divs content is just the date, you can:

```js
//Get the dates and sort it
var date = $(".grid-item").map(function() {return $(this).text().trim()}).get().sort(function(a, b) {
  var f = function(d) {[y, m, d] = d.split("-");return [y, m, d];}
  var t = new Date();
  return Math.abs(t.getTime() - new Date(...f(a)).getTime()) - Math.abs(t.getTime() - new Date(...f(b)).getTime());
});

//Assign Class
$(".grid-item").addClass('red').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === date[0];
}).removeClass('red').addClass('green');
```

```css
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item">2018-03-30</div>
<div class="grid-item">2018-04-29</div>
<div class="grid-item">2015-05-25</div>
<div class="grid-item">2015-07-26</div>
```

Using just month and day (using the current year)

```
var date = $(".grid-item").map(function() {return $(this).text().trim()}).get().sort(function(a, b) {
  var f = function(d) {[m, d] = d.split("-");return [(new Date()).getFullYear(), m, d];}
  var t = new Date();
  return Math.abs(t.getTime() - new Date(...f(a)).getTime()) - Math.abs(t.getTime() - new Date(...f(b)).getTime());
});

//Assign Class
$(".grid-item").addClass('red').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() === date[0];
}).removeClass('red').addClass('green');
```